# cannot retrieve events from google calendar using fullcalendar

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I followed the tuto about fullCalendar of Adam Shaw and I can't retrieve events from google calendar. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="<?php echo css_url().'fullcalendar.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo js_url().'jquery.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo js_url().'fullcalendar.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

    });


    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed(
             "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/username%40gmail.com/public/basic") 

    });

    });

    </script>

</head>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</html
```

Could you tell me what's wrong please?

Comment: Why do you have 2 `$(document).ready()` functions? Also, you seem to be initializing the fullCalendar twice - is this just an error in copy/paste?

Comment: Also, the link to the calendar is not valid!

Comment: @ganeshk , thank you for your answer, I'm new to JQuery. .In my code,I replace username by my username on gmail. I checked it.I deleted the second $(document).ready(). So my code is like $(document).ready(function() {

    

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed(
             "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/username%40gmail.com/public/basic") 

    });
}); it shows an empty calendar calendar although I created some events on my google calendar

Comment: @ganeshk , I also tried this  $(document).ready(function() {
var  source = {
    url: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/username%40gmail.com/public/basic'
    };
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',source);

});  but it still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate the FullCalendar only once. Replace your script tag with this and it should work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed(
             "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/username%40gmail.com/public/basic") 
      });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps.

EDIT: Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/JeDFG/. Also, please make sure `gcal.js` is in the correct path and is included in your HTML

Comment: It gives me a white page without any calendar

Comment: It gives me a white page without any calendar –

Comment: Is your google calendar public? Are you seeing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: yes it is public. You can check [link] (http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myriam.gsim%40gmail.com/public/basic) . And there is no error in my browser console

Comment: Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/JeDFG/. It works for me. Can you check if you have gcal.js included and it is in the correct path?

Comment: gcal.js wasn't in the right path. Now it works, thank you very much